# Update more than one row in dataview in slickgrid

Tags: updates, slickgrid, dataview

I am updating the slickgrid with the help of this: dataView.updateItem(args.item.id, row);
But i have a number of rows to update simultaneously.So how can i update array of rows in dataview in slickgrid?

Answer (score 3):

I assume your goal is to prevent UI updates (expensive) while updating multiple rows:

```
function updateItems (itemsToUpdate) {
  dataView.beginUpdate(); // tell your DataView to prevent re-rendering the SlickGrid on every change
  itemsToUpdate.forEach(function(item){ // iterate over each item in the array
    dataView.updateItem(item.id, item) // update the item's data
  });
  dataView.endUpdate(); // tell DataView to re-render the SlickGrid with any changes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dataView.setItems(data)` as follows

Lets say intitally you have an array of objects which you have binded in slick grid

```
var data = [
  {'id': 'l1', 'lang': 'Java'},
  {'id': 'l2', 'lang': 'JavaScript'},
  {'id': 'l3', 'lang': 'C#'},
  {'id': 'l4', 'lang': 'Python'}
           ];
```

Then you can push as many items you want in the array as follows

```
data.push({
    "id" : "l5",
    "lang" : ".net"
});
```

Then using 'dataView.setItems()' you van update your grid

```
// This will fire the change events and update the grid.
dataView.setItems(data);

OR

// You can populate the dataview with new array list if you have any
dataView.setItems(newArray);
```